httpsOnly cookie not being set in route
I'm just trying to set a httpOnly cookie from a route handler
I've stripped my code down to the bare minimum and even created a new project,
just to see if anything else is interfering, but cookies are not visible in the applications tab and are always undefined when/if returning to the route
// app/api/test/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async () => {
  const response = NextResponse.json({ message: "Testing Cookie" });

  // Set a simple cookie to verify if it's saved
  response.cookies.set("test_cookie", "12345", {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    maxAge: 3600,
    path: "/",
  });
  console.log(response);

  return response;
};

// app/page.tsx
   const Home = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Response Data:", data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    
      return <>Home page</>;
    };
    
    export default Home;

when logged in the route it returns
Response {
  status: 200,
  statusText: '',
  headers: Headers {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'set-cookie': 'test_cookie=12345; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 30 Nov 2024 16:01:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; HttpOnly',
    'x-middleware-set-cookie': 'test_cookie=12345; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 30 Nov 2024 16:01:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; HttpOnly'
  },
  body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: true },
  bodyUsed: false,
  ok: true,
  redirected: false,
  type: 'default',
  url: ''
}

I've tried in other browsers and tried with cookies() next/headers
I have a stackblitz set up
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zgcehq?description=The%20React%20framework%20for%20production&file=app%2Fpage.tsx,app%2Fapi%2Ftest%2Froute.ts&title=Next.js%20Starter
